# How can I get prioritize output of a query based on where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case-when

I have a query which is shown below

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_type_master order by standard_volume asc
```

which yields following result

```
Vehicle_Type_ID    standard_volume
 TATA ACE            20
  407                30
 20 FT               40
```

So there may arise the following condition, the query looks like

**1st Instance:**

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_type_master where Vehicle_Type_ID    = '407'
```

So for this query the desired result should come like

```
Vehicle_Type_ID    standard_volume
  407                30
TATA ACE             20
 20 FT               40
```

**2nd Instance:**

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_type_master where Vehicle_Type_ID    = '20 FT'
```

So for this query the desired result should come like

```
Vehicle_Type_ID    standard_volume
  20 FT                 40
TATA ACE                20
  407                   30
```

So whichever the condition is present in where the condition that should come first and other rows should be displayed as per `standard_volume` asc.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` with multiple `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicle_type_master  
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Vehicle_Type_ID  = '407' then 0 else 1 end) ,
standard_volume asc
```

SQLfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3907/10

most simple way you can use `IF` and `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM vehicle_type_master  
ORDER BY IF(Vehicle_Type_ID ='20 FT',0,1),standard_volume asc
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3907/9

Comment: You missed `standard_volume asc` ordering at the end.